# C++ 20: std::array as non-type template argument reshuffles elements

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++20

I recently implemented a Builder class, but I wanted to avoid throwing exceptions.  So I had an idea that I could parameterise the Builder with an array of bools representing which fields have been set.  Each setter would return a new specialisation of the Builder with the corresponding field flag set.  That way I could check that the right fields were set at compile time.

It turns out that complex data types as non-type template arguments is only available in C++ 20.  But I experimented with it anyway.

It turns out it misbehaves in a strange way.  As each new specialisation is returned, the "true" flags bunch up towards the start, as shown in this sample debug output:

```
 - set field 4 old flags 00000 new flags 00001
 - set field 2 old flags 10000 new flags 10100
 - set field 0 old flags 11000 new flags 11000
 - set field 3 old flags 11000 new flags 11010
 - set field 1 old flags 11100 new flags 11100
```

Those are from the second of the two lines below.  Removing the first fixes the problem, suggesting that the first instantiation is somehow affecting the second.

```
Fields fields1 = Builder().SetFirst(1).SetSecond(2).SetThird(3).SetFourth(4).SetFifth(5).Build();
Fields fields2 = Builder().SetFifth(5).SetThird(3).SetFirst(1).SetFourth(4).SetSecond(2).Build();
```

Is it supposed to do that?  Is this just a subtlety of C++ 20 that I'm missing somehow, or is it a bug in gcc?

I checked this with gcc 9.3.0 and gcc 10.2.0.  I also tried compiling from git, version 11.0.1 change a18ebd6c439.  Command line was `g++ -Wall --std=c++2a builder.cpp`.  They all behave the same way.  I also searched in gcc's bugzilla, but couldn't find anything that looked similar.

Below are two code samples.  First a version stripped back as far as I could to show the problem.  The second shows more context on what I was trying to achieve.  (There's a third, more realistic version, but it might be a problem to post that in public.)

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

using Flags = std::array<bool, 2>;

template<Flags flags = Flags{}>
class Builder
{
public:
    Builder() {
    }

    auto SetFirst() {
        constexpr auto new_flags = SetFieldFlag<0>();
        Builder<new_flags> new_builder;
        return new_builder;
    }

    auto SetSecond() {
        constexpr auto new_flags = SetFieldFlag<1>();
        Builder<new_flags> new_builder;
        return new_builder;
    }

    Flags GetFlags() const {
        return flags;
    }

private:
    template<int field>
    static constexpr auto SetFieldFlag() {
        auto new_flags = flags;
        std::get<field>(new_flags) = true;
        return new_flags;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto flags1 = Builder().SetFirst().SetSecond().GetFlags();
    assert(flags1[0]);
    assert(flags1[1]);

    auto flags2 = Builder().SetSecond().SetFirst().GetFlags();
    assert(flags2[0]);
    assert(flags2[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr int NumFields = 5;
using Flags = std::array<bool, NumFields>;
using Fields = std::array<int, NumFields>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Flags flags) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NumFields; ++i) {
        out << flags[i];
    }
    return out;    
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Fields fields) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NumFields; ++i) {
        out << (i ? ":" : "") << fields[i];
    }
    return out;    
}

template<Flags flags = Flags{}>
class Builder
{
public:
    Builder(Fields fields_in = Fields{})
        : fields(fields_in) {
    }

    auto SetFirst(int value) {
        fields.at(0) = value;
        return BuilderWithField<0>();
    }

    auto SetSecond(int value) {
        fields.at(1) = value;
        return BuilderWithField<1>();
    }

    auto SetThird(int value) {
        fields.at(2) = value;
        return BuilderWithField<2>();
    }

    auto SetFourth(int value) {
        fields.at(3) = value;
        return BuilderWithField<3>();
    }

    auto SetFifth(int value) {
        fields.at(4) = value;
        return BuilderWithField<4>();
    }

    Fields Build() {
        std::cout << " - build with flags " << flags << std::endl;
        static_assert(std::get<0>(flags), "first field not set");
        static_assert(std::get<1>(flags), "second field not set");
        static_assert(std::get<2>(flags), "third field not set");
        static_assert(std::get<3>(flags), "fourth field not set");
        static_assert(std::get<4>(flags), "fifth field not set");
        return fields;
    }

private:
    template<int field>
    static constexpr auto SetFieldFlag() {
        auto new_flags = flags;
        std::get<field>(new_flags) = true;
        return new_flags;
    }

    template<int field>
    auto BuilderWithField() {
        constexpr auto new_flags = SetFieldFlag<field>();
        std::cout << " - set field " << field << " old flags " << flags << " new flags " << new_flags << std::endl;
        Builder<new_flags> new_builder(fields);
        return new_builder;
    }

    Fields fields;
};

int main()
{
    Fields fields1 = Builder().SetFirst(1).SetSecond(2).SetThird(3).SetFourth(4).SetFifth(5).Build();
    std::cout << fields1 << std::endl;

    Fields fields2 = Builder().SetFifth(5).SetThird(3).SetFirst(1).SetFourth(4).SetSecond(2).Build();
    std::cout << fields2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used https://godbolt.org/ to examine the generated code for multiple compilers and **this is indeed a bug in gcc**. Both clang and msvc produce correct results.

Here's the interesting part, the assembler generated for the method `Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{}>::SetSecond()` which causes the error in your shorter example. The actual code is not that important, the error can be seen by looking at the types:

[Clang produces (correctly) this:](https://godbolt.org/z/Eq8Mqr)

```
Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{}>::SetSecond(): # @Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{}>::SetSecond()
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
    mov     ax, word ptr [.L__const.Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{}>::SetSecond().new_flags]
    mov     word ptr [rbp - 16], ax
    lea     rdi, [rbp - 24]
    call    Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{bool [2]{false, true}}>::Builder() [base object constructor]
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

[GCC produces (incorrectly) this:](https://godbolt.org/z/bbM6b4)

```
Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{}>::SetSecond():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 40
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rdi
    mov     WORD PTR [rbp-18], 0
    mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-17], 1
    lea     rax, [rbp-19]
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    Builder<std::array<bool, 2ul>{bool [2]{true}}>::Builder() [complete object constructor]
    nop
    mov     eax, ebx
    mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    leave
    ret
```

If you compare the type of the function that gets `call`ed, you can clearly see that in gcc, `SetSecond()` did not set the second -- there's `{true}`, but should be `{false, true}`.

So, time to switch to clang?

Comment: Ha!  Actually I normally work in clang, but when I learned that this feature wasn't supported until C++ 20, I somehow got the impression that g++ was the easiest way to experiment with C++ 20.  In fact it's all moot: in real life I'm stuck with C++ 14 anyway.  But at least with this evidence I can submit a bug report to gcc's bugzilla.  So thanks!

Comment: Bug reported to gcc here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99460